# Wpml and Custom Widgets

Tags: php, wordpress, translate, po, wpml

In WPML some times custom widgets developed could not get translated.

Any string is translatable if the you copy paste the string then that string if searchable in WPML is translatable.

I have a website that has 4-5 Custom widgets + some hard coded part

For example there was a string in hard coded part-

## Bet on your favorite sports online

I made it WPML compatible-
WPML version

N.B. Before posting the question here I have invested around 3-4 hours in understanding all the FAQ's at wpml.org site.

My problem-

I have various widgets, one such widgets has this portion-

```
<div class="signupoffers">
        <div class="signupText"> <h2><?php echo $signup_text_title?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $signup_text_content?></p><br>
        </div>
        <div class="signupbuttonDiv">
            <div class="RegisterBlock">
                <div class="block"><h2><?php echo $signup_btn_title?></h2>
                    <div>
                        <?php echo $signup_btn_content; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php //nsu_signup_form();?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lets take an example this one-
I tried this     http://screencast.com/t/3hJCPJgylXS
but the above one doesn't worked.

and various other versions, but no help so far.

Content here is coming dynamically from widget entry. May be I have some syntax issue. Does any one has encountered such situation before, Please guide me how to do that. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually the code that I have shown in screencast was not getting posted properly thats the reason I have used screencast.

Answer (score 0):

Let me ask the question in different way-
The string here is coming in a dynamic format-

```
<h2><?php echo $signup_btn_title?></h2>
```

How to convert it into wpml version so that wpml can read and search this string.

I tried this one, but it didn't worked-

```
<h2><?php _e('(<?php echo $seocontent_text_title;?>)','Casino'); ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2><?php _e('(<?php echo $seocontent_text_title;?>)','Casino'); ?></h2>
```

this is definitely wrong

If any of similar approach, it should read similarly to this:

```
<?php _e( $seocontent_text_title, 'your_text_domain' ); ?>
```

You would probably also need to edit/create a wpml-config.xml file.

You could also try something along this lines: 
(icl_translate function in strings)

```
<?php echo icl_translate(context, name, value); ?>">
```

I think this could help you to understand further:

https://wpml.org/forums/topic/transform-echo-to-php_e/

https://wpml.org/documentation/support/translation-for-texts-by-other-plugins-and-themes/

https://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/